# Error <'NoneType' object is not callable> al intentar seleccionar elemento por id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy intentando llegar a un elemento del DOM que tiene un determinado `id`. El problema es que estoy usando el método `.getElementsById()` de *AdvancedHTMLParser*, que está disponible en su [guía](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AdvancedHTMLParser/5.0.1).

Una vez extraigo el HTML de la [URL](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/batman-the-enemy-within-the-complete-season-episodes-1-5/c0dgrh3hk0vk), busco el elemento del DOM de esta forma:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

bundle = page_soup.getElementById("pdpbundleparts")
```

Pero me devuelve un error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

La web se descarga bien.

Comment: ¿Que es soup? Parece sintaxis de BeautifulSoup usando html.parser de la biblioteca estándar pero usas un método de AdvancedHTMLParser directamente...

Comment: Sí, estoy usando BeautifulSoup para parsear la URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si usas ***BeautifulSoup*** para parsear la html, estás usando [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)  como parser, dados los argumentos que pasas al inicializador (`page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")`). El problema es que estás usando un método (`getElementById`) de otro parser (*AdvancedHTMLParser*) y no los métodos propios de BS para seleccionar elementos (`find`, `find_all`, ...).

Que yo sepa [`AdvancedHTMLParser`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/AdvancedHTMLParser) no puede ser usado como parser interno en BS (están disponibles [`lxml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/4.1.1), [`html5lib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib) y [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) de la biblioteca estándar), pero puedes usar `html.parser` sin problemas en tu caso:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/batman-the-enemy-within-the-complete-season-episodes-1-5/c0dgrh3hk0vk"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9'}
request = requests.get(url,  headers = header)
page_html = request.text

page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
bundle = page_soup.find(id="pdpbundleparts")
```

---

Si lo deseas, en vez de ***BeautifulSoup*** puedes usar ***AdvancedHTMLParser*** directamente sin problemas:

```
import requests
import AdvancedHTMLParser

url = "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/batman-the-enemy-within-the-complete-season-episodes-1-5/c0dgrh3hk0vk"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/2.0.0.9'}
request = requests.get(url,  headers = header)
page_html = request.text

parser = AdvancedHTMLParser.AdvancedHTMLParser()
parser.parseStr(page_html)
bundle = parser.getElementById("pdpbundleparts")
```

> **Nota:** En ambos casos uso [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) para obtener el html para que el ejemplo sea reproducible. Es necesario proveer un falso *User-Agent* para que el servidor no nos mande a paseo...

Comment: ¡Gracias! No conocía esa división.

Comment: @JetLagFox BS permite usar diferentes parsers html/xml, hasta donde yo se se pueden usar [`lxml`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/4.1.1), [`html5lib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib) y `html.parser`. Este último es parte de la biblioteca estándar de Python, los otros dos debes descargarlos si los quieres usar con BeutifulSoup. `AdvancedHTMLParser` es otro parser (algo vitaminado ya que posee otras funciones de scraping, validación, etc) que no esta disponible para ser usado como parser interno en BS pero que es una buena alternativa, aunque no me gusta su documentación :( . Un saludo.